# Connections Refresh All "System.OutOfMemoryException". Manual refresh queries = works

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery, vba

I have an `Excel` .xlsm with 37 Workbook Queries organized into groups. When I click the "Refresh All" connections I get a "System.OutOfMemoryException".

[image]

However, if I manually refresh one group at a time, I don't get the error.

I created a macro that refreshes the `listobject` items by groups. Unfortunately, I have to manually trigger the Macro's since I'm unable to use VBA listeners to accurately know when a query has finished loading.

Is there a way to "Refresh All" connections without getting a "System.OutOfMemoryException"?

Note: I wrote macro's but I wasn't able to detect when a macro completed loading and refreshing the screen.

```
 - DoEvents
 - CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
 - EnableLivePreview = False
 - Application Calculation manual
```

Note: I am unable to modify computer hardware like RAM or move to 64 bit version.

Comment: In short you need more memory on your computer, or you need to enable your application to use more of your available memory. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/909678/you-may-receive-the-system-outofmemoryexception-error-message-when-you-use-sql-server-reporting-services

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for the info. The information in the link mentions `Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Reporting Services` and `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services`

Do these symptoms apply to `Microsoft Excel`?

Comment: When you run your queries I am assuming you are running SQL connection queries, which have to run somewhere through a SQL application. Are you running some other type of query?

Comment: @TylerH The queries were created using "Get & Transform" (formerly powerquery_ > From File > From Workbook.  The queries are pulling data from Excel workbooks.  In addition, the max number of cells in each query is maybe 50.  So, it's a small amount of information.

Comment: The issues are similar between Excel and SQL Server (too much data). If you can, updating to a 64-bit version of Excel may resolve this issue.

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, I'm restricted to 32-bit version.  
I don't believe I have much data. I'm thinking MAX 2,000 cells.  Limitations are here[https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Power-Query-specifications-and-limits-5FB2807C-1B16-4257-AA5B-6793F051A9F4]

Is there a way to calculate the numbers of cells in the queries or determine the amount of memory used?